# How RPM detect conflicts?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Recently, I was building a rpm package. I ran `sudo rpm -ivh A.rpm`, but got an error `file _binary_ from install of A conflicts with file from package B`, I came across this problem before, it's because of the difference in the  _binary_ made by me. Now I check _binary_ in two rpms, there are the same, I want to ask are there other specific reasons causing conflicts in the procedure of rpm installation?

I dumped a installed package, it outputed like

`$rpm -ql --dump khotfix-g4hk4hzq-2.6.32-220.23.2.ali878.el6.x86_64-1.0-1.el6.x86_64
...
/usr/local/sbin/ksplice-undo 6436 1428483796 f3dbddfb7820413cc4d97cda2df9388a 0100755 root root 0 0 0 X
...`

`ksplice-undo` is md5 is `f3dbddfb7820413cc4d97cda2df9388a`

And I dumped a package to be installed, it outputed like

`$rpm -qlp --dump khotfix-35692936-2.6.32-220.23.2.ali878.el6.x86_64-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
...
/usr/local/sbin/ksplice-undo 6436 1437038808 a6dc8be59d4a2627b73240adcca41716d8ea0001d9d5cd973694e8779ef9d6b1 0100755 root root 0 0 0 X
...`

`ksplice-undo` md5 is `a6dc8be59d4a2627b73240adcca41716d8ea0001d9d5cd973694e8779ef9d6b1`

Then I ran `$cat /usr/local/sbin/ksplice-undo | md5sum`, output is `f3dbddfb7820413cc4d97cda2df9388a`.

I uncompressed the packaged to be installed, by running `$rpm2cpio khotfix-35692936-2.6.32-220.23.2.ali878.el6.x86_64-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm | cpio -div`
, and `$cat ./usr/local/sbin/ksplice-undo | md5sum`, output is `f3dbddfb7820413cc4d97cda2df9388a`

So, I guess it's the md5 in the dump output cause the conflicts,and the hashed value is longer than md5 outputs. Higher version rpm use sha256 to hash file contents, but lower version rpm use md5 to hash file contens.

Answer (score 2):

rpm looks at the pathnames used in the [`%files`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html) section, taking into account those which you have told it to ignore using the [`%exclude`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786101/excluding-file-types-when-packaging-an-rpm) tag.  While you can *override* it using the [`--replacefiles`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html) option, and install conflicting files, this is not (usually) a good idea since updates to the packages will require additional overrides, and frequently yum upgrades will fail.

Because rpm only looks at this list of pathnames, you can (at a cost of complexity) design add-on packages which rename another package's files during the pre/post-install scripts (and place their *own* files in the places needed).  For instance, I have found this useful in some cases where a vendor has packaged their product's configuration files without marking them in the spec-file with [`%config`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html).  It does interfere with `rpm -V` to verify a package, but the alternatives seem to be worse.

Answer (score 0):

rpm doesn't care about the contents of the file. It cares that two packages claim to own the file. It doesn't allow that (except for two of the same package with different architectures owning a common file I think).

The file may be the same at the moment but that may not be the case later. It also complicates what rpm has to do when one of the packages is removed (does it delete the file or not)?

In short, don't have two packages that contain the same file.

Comment: What determine a package the same? I installed packages owning same files, but now it outputs conflicts, I don't know how to check the problems.

Comment: If two different packages (different names) try to install the same file RPM will complain. It does not allow that. What packages are you dealing with here?

Comment: It's  not a public package, it's made by myself (used to hot update Linux kernel by Ksplice, and Ksplice is decided not to be removed even after uninstallation ). Is there any possibility that lower version rpm allow the same name file (contents also same), but high version rpm not allow the same file name  (not to say contents)? I test it on rhel5, it was ok, but rhel6 failed.

Comment: It is entirely possible that newer versions of rpm got more strict though I don't think they did in this area (but I haven't tried it to know). What file(s) are you packaging that some other package already owns? Kernel image files?

Comment: Perl scripts wrapping Ksplice to hot update, because if it's removed, other patches belonging to other packages can not be undo anymore.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ksplice in practice so maybe I'm just missing it but I don't see what scripts you would need to package in your rpm that are also packaged by some other rpm. Do you just need to have your package list some other package as a requirement to prevent that other package from being removed while your package is still installed?

Comment: I guess you mean dependencies? Yes I think a dependency it's better, make ksplice and patches as seperate packages. But this spec is decided to do like in that way (by my company), I am deciding to write a small case to check how strict the conflicts detection is, I will response latter.

Comment: Why are you having two packages contain the same file? An upgraded package doesn't conflict with itself. Only two *different* packages? Why are you writing two packages that contain the same files?

Comment: It's historic problem some one leave to me, I don't know why..., and a lot of packages have been applied to online machines, so I decide to use lower version rpmbuild (wich, I guess, use md5 to hash file contents instead of SHA256) to have a try.

Comment: The sums of the files don't factor in here. The path is the problem. You can continue trying to work around the problem (which you can do in a number of ways) or you can try to fix the problem and **stop** packaging the same files in multiple packages.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding a workaround to force hash algorithm

```
%global _source_filedigest_algorithm    md5
%global _binary_filedigest_algorithm    md5
```

But as @Etan Reisner said, it is not really good design, I should rearrange the package files to independent packages.

And from the steps I took, rpm check hash value to detect conflicts, but hash algorithm may vary.

Answer (score 0):

rpm does care about file conflicts (two or more packages owning the same file but those files not being identical (or multilib-related)) and package conflicts.

http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/MultipleVersions